# Show complete breadcrumb in Opencart 1.5.6.4

Tags: html, css, opencart, breadcrumbs

I have installed one clean version of Opencart v1.5.6.4 and one for v1.5.5.1. Now there is a difference between the versions in how the breadcrumb behaves when you click on a product on the homepage. If I click on a product on the homepage the breadcrumb for version 1.5.5.1. is **home > category-name > product-name**, but for version 1.5.6.4 it is **home > product-name**. Do you have any idea where this difference comes from? It is something in the template or the version of Opencart or in the settings maybe? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On category product url:

> ?route=product/product&path=18&product_id=47

Home page product url:

> ?route=product/product&product_id=47

```
when category page to display full breadcrumb with category 
name using " path=18 " get category id 18 to name.
```

[Full breadcrumb url](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9609&filter_search=breadcrumb)  Using this you can get full breadcrumb for home page product or other place.

[image]

[How to install vqmode](http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/vQmod)

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want to modify code without using extension. Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: this extension but this was auto modify your code using vQmode just install vqmode and add this xml file. or you can direct change code just see the xml and put code in your file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VQMOD to edit it

```
<modification>
<id>Always display categories in breadcrumb trail</id>
<author>Casey Faber</author>
<email>kc@caseyfaber.com</email>

<file name="catalog/model/catalog/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before" index="1"><![CDATA[public function getTotalProducts($data = array()) {]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
    public function getCategoriesByProductId($product_id) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

      return $query->rows;
    }
  ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file name="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="before"><![CDATA[public function upload() {]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
    protected function getPath($parent_id, $current_path = '') {
                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($parent_id);

                if ($category_info) {
                    if (!$current_path) {
                        $new_path = $category_info['category_id'];
                    } else {
                        $new_path = $category_info['category_id'] . '_' . $current_path;
                    }   

                    $path = $this->getPath($category_info['parent_id'], $new_path);

                    if ($path) {
                        return $path;
                    } else {
                        return $new_path;
                    }
                }
            }
  ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[if ($product_info) {]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
    if(!isset($category_info)) {
      $categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategoriesByProductId($this->request->get['product_id']);
      if($categories) {
        foreach($categories as $category){
          $path = $this->getPath($category['category_id']);
          $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category['category_id']);
          if($path){
            $cat_path = $path;
          }else{
            $cat_path = $category_info['category_id'];
          }

          if($category_info) {
            $path = '';
            foreach (explode('_', $cat_path) as $path_id) {
              if (!$path) {
                $path = $path_id;
              } else {
                $path .= '_' . $path_id;
              }

              $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

              if ($category_info) {
                $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                  'text'      => $category_info['name'],
                  'href'      => $this->url->link('product/category', '&path=' . $path),
                  'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
                );
              }
            }
            break;
          }

        }
      }
    }
  ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```